# Django REST ListCreateAPIView Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a new object with a foreign key with django's ListCreateAPIView. The reference to the foreign key is in the url. I tried using lookup_url_kwarg but when I send a json, it still requires me to input an institution

**views.py**

```
class MemorandumCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):
    # permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Memorandum.objects.all()
    lookup_fields = 'institution_id'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'institution_id'
    serializer_class = MemorandumSerializer


    def get_queryset(self):
        institution = self.lookup_url_kwarg['institution_id']
        return Memorandum.objects.filter(institution=institution)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class MemorandumSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    # lookup_fields = 'institution_id'
    class Meta:
        model = Memorandum
        fields = "__all__"
```

**urls.py**

```
 url(r'^(?P<institution_id>(\d+))/memorandums', MemorandumCreateView.as_view()),
```

**models.py**

```
class Memorandum(Model):
    MEMORANDUM_CATEGORIES = (
        ('MOA', 'Memorandum of Agreement'),
        ('MOU', 'Memorandum of Understanding')
    )
    AGREEMENT_TYPES = (
        ('B', 'Bilateral'),
        ('M', 'Multilateral')
    )

    institution = ForeignKey(Institution)
    agreement = CharField(max_length=12, choices=AGREEMENT_TYPES)
    memorandum_category = CharField(max_length=3, choices=MEMORANDUM_CATEGORIES)
    memorandum_file = CharField(max_length=512)
    version_date = DateField()
    date_effective = DateField()
    date_expiration = DateField(null=True)
    college_initiator = CharField(max_length=5, choices=COLLEGES, null=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lookup_field` not `lookup_fields`.  Once this is set the `lookup_field_kwarg` will default to using the same one.

In your model:

`institution = ForeignKey(Institution)` needs to have the `null=True` parameter if you want to be able to create a Memorandum without an associated Institution.  I believe the ModelSerializer will pick up on that change and set `allow_null=True` on the PrimaryKeyRelatedField it creates for you.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#core-arguments

Answer (score 3):

You could grab the `institution_id` from your URL, then use it in a custom `perform_create`:

```
class MemorandumCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):
    ...
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        institution = Institution.objects.get(id = self.kwargs['institution_id'])
        serializer.save(institution = institution)
```

Comment: when I send a json without the 'institution' field, it returns to me a serializer error. Shouldnt it extract the data from the url?

Comment: I fixed it by adding an exclude in serializer thanks!